# Using go command in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In SSMS if I want to `create` table and `insert` some values there with one query, I can separate those two commands with `go`; However I cannot use go in stored procedure. What can I do?

Comment: `GO` is not a command.  It is an indicator that a batch of commands should run and is not appropriate in a stored procedure.

Comment: Use two procedures

Answer (score 1):

GO is a utility command that is not required in SPs.

When you use this command within  common sql statements,SQL Server interprets it as a signal to send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server.

Write your 'Create Table ' and 'Insert' statements ordinally and put one 'GO' command at the end of your SP.

SQL server will create your table and then uses it in a single batch of Transact-SQL statements.

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL command and is not recognized by SQL Server. It is the client application (e.g. SSMS, SQLCMD, etc.) that interprets the `GO` batch terminator commands and sends the preceding batch of SQL statement to the database engine for execution.

Answer (score 1):

GO is not a statement but a command to the server to commit the current batch to the Database. It creates a stop inside the current transaction.

You can't use GO inside a stored procedure. If you would try, the definition of the procedure will end there, and the rest will be a separate batch.

A local variable has the scope of the batch, so after a GO command you can't use local variables declared before the GO command:

```
declare @test int

set @test = 42

GO

select @Test -- causes an error message as @Test is undefined
```